# Angular 2 click fired multiple times inside ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very weird problem (never saw before) with my component. I'm trying to remove a line when clicking on a button inside a ngFor list. When I have only one line it works but when It's more than one line the event is fired twice, once for the good line and once for the first line (after deleted the other line) :

```
<label>
    <div class="tag" *ngFor="let o of selectedOptions;">
        <span class="tag-text">{{ o.textContent }}</span>
        <button (click)="removeTag(o)" type="button" class="fa fa-times"></button>
    </div>
</label>
```

And here is my method witch is called twice (only if there is more that one "option") :

```
public removeTag (option: NxtSelectOptionComponent) {
    this.selectedOptions = [
        ...this.selectedOptions.filter(o => o !== option),
    ]
}
```

I've tried to use splice, I've tried to add stopPropagation... I don't understand I've done it tons of time and this is the first time I see that.

EDIT : the removeTag method is called  when I click on `.tag` element this is why when I click on the button it is called twice, but I can't figure this out why... the `(click)` attribute is only on the button

Problem resolved : I've found the problem... FYI label tag will click on the button so if you have any (click) attribute it'll fired twice.

Comment: Did you check your filter function? isn't it a problem? 
Did you try putting some `console.log()` inside the removeTag() function to see if it's called twice? Maybe you should try to `console.log(this.selectedOptions)` at the end of the removeTag function to see what's been changed.

Let us know if there is something new, because for now it's weird. Your code is good, so...

Comment: Thank you
I don't have any filter function. The removeTag is called twice. I've found that it is called even if I click on the .tag element (witch is why removeTag is called twice) I don't know why and if I click on the .tag element, the target (inside the event object) is the first button of the list o_O !

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: I've found the problem... FYI label tag will click on the button so if you have any (click) attribute it'll fired twice.

Answer (score 11):

Actually the second click will be called by the parent element.
The browsers default behavior is, to trigger a click on the input, once the parent got clicked.

Use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to stop second trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning my situation in case it is tripping anyone else up. The component which housed the buttons was subscribed to an observable and never unsubscribed so this was keeping old components alive and firing their click methods. Make sure to .unsubscribe() any subscriptions you create in the button's parent component.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It got me thinking in the right direction to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Full solution:

```
<label>
    <div class="tag" *ngFor="let o of selectedOptions;">
        <span class="tag-text">{{ o.textContent }}</span>
        <button (click)="removeTag(o, $event)" type="button" class="fa fa-times"></button>
    </div>
</label>
```

Then the method that takes the event:

```
public removeTag (option: NxtSelectOptionComponent, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // This is needed to prevent the click event from firing twice on a label
    this.selectedOptions = [
        ...this.selectedOptions.filter(o => o !== option),
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index" >
    {{user.name}}
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUser(i)">-</a>
    </div>
</div>

removeUser(i): void {
    this.users.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've already tried to remove by index with splice but I have the same issue... :(

Comment: in that case something else is problem, this works for me